# Number of Labels doesn't match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

So I'm trying to use Extra Tree Classifier in order to find the paramter importance in my dataset, but for someone reason everytime I run the code it tells me the that the number of labels do not match the number of samples, and I really don't know hot to fix it, my dataset has no nan,zero or empty cells. It consists of 13 columns with all have the same number of rows.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline


from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier 


from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)



# Loading First Dataframe

link = '............'

fluff, id = link.split('=')
print (id) # Verify that you have everything after '='
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('Final After Simple Filtering.csv')  
df = pd.read_csv('Final After Simple Filtering.csv',index_col=None,low_memory=True)
df = df.astype(float)


ExtraT = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators =250,random_state=0,bootstrap=False,min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.4) 

y=df['Power_kW']

df=df.drop(df['Power_kW'])

X=df


ExtraT.fit(X,y)

feature_importance = ExtraT.feature_importances_ 

feature_importance_normalized = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in ExtraT.estimators_], axis = 1)

plt.bar(X.columns, feature_importance) 
plt.xlabel('Lable') 
plt.ylabel('Feature Importance') 
plt.title('Parameters Importance') 
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a213399da605> in <module>()
     48 #y= df.iloc[:, 0]
     49 
---> 50 ExtraT.fit(X,y)
     51 
     52 feature_importance = ExtraT.feature_importances_

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    263         if len(y) != n_samples:
    264             raise ValueError("Number of labels=%d does not match "
--> 265                              "number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))
    266         if not 0 <= self.min_weight_fraction_leaf <= 0.5:
    267             raise ValueError("min_weight_fraction_leaf must in [0, 0.5]")

ValueError: Number of labels=10049972 does not match number of samples=10043104
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is `len(y)` and `len(X)` ?

Comment: Try `df=df.drop('Power_kW', axis=1)` and tell us if this helps.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I did and I got 

KeyError: '[222.0 222.0 329.0 ... 21.0 23.0 23.0] not found in axis'

Comment: @YOLO X is 10043104 and y is 10049972

Comment: there you go, that's the error. now check why is that.

Comment: @YOLO this is really weird, because when I run df.describe it says all my columns have the same number of count which is 1.004997e+07 , or RangeIndex: 10049972 entries, 0 to 10049971

Comment: I think there would be some objects created in memory causing this trouble, try restarting your notebook and run the code

Comment: @YOLO i restarted runtime on google colab and tried using jupyter notebook directly, still the same error.